# R - substr over multiple columns in Dataframe

Tags: r, string, substring, lapply

Lets say I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
Column1,  Column2,  Column3
 a_2019    b_2020    c_2021
 d_2019    e_2020    f_2021
 a_2019    b_2020    c_2021
 d_2019    e_2020    f_2021
```

And I would like to take out "_2019", "_2020", and "_2021". I could use

```
df$Column1 <- substr(df$Column1, 1, nchar(df$Column1)-5)
```

For every column, but I have multiple dataframes with quite a few columns. substr need a text or a vector for it to work, so using `df[,3:10]` doesn´t work, `lapply` either.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this in an elegant way? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using `lapply` along with `sub` for a base R option:

```r
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) sub("_(?:2019|2020|2021)$", "", x))
```

Here `cols` should be a vector containing the column names on which you seek to make the replacement.

More generally, to target underscore followed by any number, we can use:

```r
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) sub("_\\d+$", "", x))  # or _\\d{4} for a year
```

Comment: This is very heplful but `lapply` returns a list rather than a data.frame. With `sapply` you can get a data.frame. Also, while the syntax is more complex, it's much faster than the `dplyr` solution in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
       mutate(across(3:10, ~ substr(.x, 1, nchar(.x)-5)))
```